# CONNECT through proxy doesn't include my headers

Tags: c#, http, webclient

OK, simple question, but it needs some explaining before I can get to it.

I'm trying to download an https page through a proxy server, using System.Net.WebClient (or WebRequest, same result).

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             var wc = new WebClient();
             wc.Proxy = new WebProxy("MyProxyAddress") { UseDefaultCredentials = true };
             wc.Headers.Add("xyz", "abc");

            try
            {
                 Console.WriteLine(wc.DownloadString("https://www.google.co.nz"));
            }
            catch (WebException wex)
            {
                if (wex.Response != null)
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(wex.Response.GetResponseStream()))
                        Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I fire up Fiddler at this point, I can see the request looks as below. Note that I've set Fiddler to Require Proxy Authentication.

```
CONNECT www.google.co.nz:443 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.co.nz
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Response will be

```
HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Auth Required
Connection: close
```

, as expected. If I change the address from https://... to http://..., I get this. Note that the xyz header is now shown

```
GET http://www.google.co.nz/ HTTP/1.1
xyz: abc
Host: www.google.co.nz
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
```

All fine and well, except if the proxy that I'm going through requires a User-Agent. All headers, including my User-Agent, are stripped from the request and thus the proxy denies the request. If I configure Fiddler to force a User-Agent header into the request, it all works OK.

So, why are my headers not included with the CONNECT request? Is this a MS bug, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

HTTPS through web proxies works like this:

1. Client sends `CONNECT` request to the proxy - that's what you're seeing in Fiddler.
2. Proxy agrees to connect, returns `200 CONNECTED`, and now functions as a logic-less data pump

   - If proxy requires authentication, it would return `407 Proxy Auth Required`, and client would make the same `CONNECT` request with proper proxy auth.
3. Client can now communicate directly with the real server, through the proxy which blindly data-pumps data.

   - Normally, client would perform HTTPS session negotiation, and then send the "real" HTTP request over the encrypted session.

I'm not 100% familiar with `WebClient`, but I assume that the headers added would apply only to the "real" HTTP request (3 above). you might be able to do something with your `WebProxy` instance, though I didn't find any solution there either.

Comment: The problem is, the proxy is expecting certain headers during the auth negotiation, i.e. second part of step 2. Surely I'm not the only guy trying to add headers to the CONNECT request?